# How can I write SQL for a self-referencing SELECT where some field NOT LIKE same field and a few other criteria?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-like, exists

I have the following (simplified) table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resource` (
  `id`         INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `host`       TEXT NOT NULL,
  `inspecting` INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
  `visitedAt`  TEXT
);
```

There can be multiple records with the same `host` value and/or a value that is considered a subdomain of `host`. So for example:

```
 id |      host       | inspecting |      visitedAt
---------------------------------------------------------
  1 |     example.com |          0 |                null
  2 |     example.com |          0 | 2020-09-28 00:00:00
  3 | sub.example.com |          1 |                null
  4 |     example.org |          0 |                null
```

So, these hosts may have been visited or can currently be inspected. I want to find the oldest host that has not recently been visited and is not currently being inspected and whose host is not considered a subdomain of a recently visited or currently inspected host either.

So, let's say `example.com` is currently being inspected or has recently been visited, then I don't want to match `example.com` or `sub.example.com`. In the above data sample `example.org` should match.

I've tried various queries with `JOIN`s and `WHERE (NOT) EXISTS`, but I just can't get it to work.

The query that came closest was something like (might not be accurate, though):

```sql
SELECT `self`.*
FROM `resource` AS `self`
WHERE 
  `self`.`inspecting` != 1 AND 
  (`self`.`visitedAt` IS NULL OR datetime( `self`.`visitedAt` ) <= datetime( 'now', '-10 minutes' )) AND
  NOT EXISTS (  
    SELECT 1
    FROM 
      `resource` AS `probe`
    WHERE
      `probe`.`inspecting` = 1 AND 
      (`self`.`host` = `probe`.`host` OR `self`.`host` LIKE "%." || `probe`.`host`) AND 
      (`probe`.`visitedAt` IS NOT NULL AND datetime( `probe`.`visitedAt` ) > datetime( 'now', '-10 minutes' ))
  )
ORDER BY `self`.`visitedAt` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Is it possible to filter out such a row with a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a common table expression with sub-queries in the select to create conditional columns like so:

```sql
WITH `t` AS (
  SELECT  
    -- Create a conditional column `inspectionFlag`
    CASE WHEN
    (
    -- Checks the `resource` table for hosts that has inspecting = 1
     SELECT 1 FROM `resource` AS `probe` 
      WHERE (`probe`.`host` LIKE '%.' || `self`.`host` OR `self`.`host` LIKE '%.' || `probe`.`host` OR `self`.`host` = `probe`.`host`)
      AND `probe`.`inspecting` = 1
    ) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    AS `inspectionFlag`,
    CASE 
    WHEN     
    -- Checks the `resource` table for hosts that are being visited
    (SELECT 1 FROM `resource` AS `probe`
            WHERE (`probe`.`host` LIKE '%.' || `self`.`host` OR `self`.`host` LIKE '%.' || `probe`.`host` OR `self`.`host` = `probe`.`host`)
      AND `probe`.`visitedAt` IS NOT NULL
      AND datetime( `probe`.`visitedAt` ) > datetime( 'now', '-10 minutes' )
    ) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    AS `visitedFlag`
  , `self`.*
  FROM `resource` AS `self`
) 
SELECT `t`.* FROM `t`
```

The results should now look like this:

```
| inspectionFlag | visitedFlag | id  | host            | inspecting | visitedAt           |
| -------------- | ----------- | --- | --------------- | ---------- | ------------------- |
| 1              | 1           | 1   | example.com     | 0          |                     |
| 1              | 1           | 2   | example.com     | 0          | 2020-09-28 08:00:00 |
| 1              | 1           | 3   | sub.example.com | 1          |                     |
| 0              | 0           | 4   | example.org     | 0          |                     |
```

Now it is just a matter of using the new "flag" columns to filter out the host, like so:

```sql
WITH `t` AS (
  SELECT  
    CASE WHEN
    (
     SELECT 1 FROM `resource` AS `probe` 
      WHERE (`probe`.`host` LIKE '%.' || `self`.`host` OR `self`.`host` LIKE '%.' || `probe`.`host` OR `self`.`host` = `probe`.`host`)
      AND `probe`.`inspecting` = 1
    ) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    AS `inspectionFlag`,
    CASE 
    WHEN     
    (SELECT 1 FROM `resource` AS `probe`
            WHERE (`probe`.`host` LIKE '%.' || `self`.`host` OR `self`.`host` LIKE '%.' || `probe`.`host` OR `self`.`host` = `probe`.`host`)
      AND `probe`.`visitedAt` IS NOT NULL
      AND datetime( `probe`.`visitedAt` ) > datetime( 'now', '-10 minutes' )
    ) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    AS `visitedFlag`
  , `self`.*
  FROM `resource` AS `self`
) 
SELECT `t`.* FROM `t`
WHERE `t`.`inspectionFlag` = 0 AND `t`.`visitedFlag` = 0
```

Results:

```
| inspectionFlag | visitedFlag | id  | host        | inspecting | visitedAt |
| -------------- | ----------- | --- | ----------- | ---------- | --------- |
| 0              | 0           | 4   | example.org | 0          |           |
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I need time to analyze and test your answer though, because that's a lot too take in. :-) Two things I want to point out already though: 1) Unless I am misunderstanding the `inspectionFlag`, it looks like it is being set when it's not supposed to, even though it appears to give the correct final result. 2) The queries are really slow at the moment (> 10 sec.) for a few thousand records. But that could very well be because I haven't defined any indexes yet (and I should probably invert the host field values also, for better indexing).

Comment: Never mind about my first point. I get it: it's because *any* of the hosts in the same domain matches the `inspecting` field, right?

Comment: Correct, perhaps I misunderstood what you wanted? You can modify the `WHERE` clause in the sub-queries as you see fit, I'm talking about this part of the query: `\`probe\`.\`host\` LIKE \'%.\' || \`self\`.\`host\` OR \`self\`.\`host\` LIKE '%.' || \`probe\`.\`host\` OR \`self\`.\`host\` = \`probe\`.\`host\`` @DecentDabbler

Comment: No, no, no, not at all. You've understood perfectly well what I am going for! Very clever stuff! I just need to find a way to optimize it. But you've given me a very good starting point. So, thanks again! And because I'm a bit tired I overlooked the fact that point 1) also applied to the `visitedFlag` field. ;-)

Comment: You're most welcome! Do mark the answer as the accepted one if you deem it appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, with that I think you offered a solution for finding whether host is a subdomain OR host is a parent domain, which was a problem I had in the back of my mind as well, that I didn't want to address in the question, but you conveniently appeared to have solved simultaneously. So that's great as well!

Comment: Another thing I would like to note is that if you don't necessarily need both flags, you can always just combine them into one.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to wait for a few other answers. See if there are other alternatives. But if your answer comes out as best, I will surely mark it as solved. I've upvoted your answer already for the effort you've put in — really appreciate it!

Comment: I've fiddled with your query, but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work fast enough. The optimizations I made where: individual indexes on `host`, `inspecting` and `visitedAt`; reversed all `host` values (i.e. `example.org` => `gro.elpmaxe`) such that the index on `host` can be used with wildcards at the end of `LIKE` conditions (i.e. `` `probe`.`host` LIKE `self`.`host` || '.%' ``. But with roughly 2500 records, it already takes 2777ms. So even though your answer looks promising, I don't know how to further optimize it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222157/discussion-between-liew-xun-and-decent-dabbler).

Comment: I feel so silly now: one thing I forgot to try it with was with `LIMIT 1`. That all made it execute in 10ms. Even without your suggested combining of flags (and testing it in SQLite Browser may have caused additional lag as well). Furthermore, with your suggestions about `OR`ing the flags, I appear to have made my original query work as well (with `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, in stead of with CTE), by `OR`ing on the same conditions. I still need to thoroughly test to make sure the results are as expected, but you pointed me in the right direction. So thank you once more!